# mySQL statement not running in PHP variable declaration

Tags: php, mysql

In the following code I'm attempting to connect to my database, pull the maximum ID from my table and then generate a random number using the the `rand()` function. The code successfully connects me to the the database but when I try to call for the maximum ID it won't return a value.

When I try to echo the variable, it returns SELECT MAX(id) FROM 'file'.

```
<?php

// Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error()); }


    $amount = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM 'table'";
    $rannmr = rand(1, $amount);


// Close the mysql connection
    mysqli_close($dbLink);

?>
```

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> *When I try to echo the variable, it returns SELECT MAX(id) FROM 'file'.*

*Firstly*, you are using the wrong [**identifier**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for `FROM 'table'` being single quotes.

If `table` is indeed the table's name, wrap it in backticks, your question shows `file`.

```
$amount = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table`";
```

***Either way,*** you cannot use quotes around a table name. It appears you are using `file` as your table name.

So if `table` is only an example and it is called `file` *let's just say*, you would do:

```
$amount = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM `file`";
```

or

```
$amount = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM file";
```

***Then,*** you also need to query, using [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) which you are not doing.

```
$amount = mysqli_query($dbLink,"SELECT MAX(id) FROM `file`");
```

Or Object oriented style:

```
$amount = $dbLink->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM `file`");

if($amount){
    echo "Success!";
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $dbLink->errno .') '. $dbLink->error);
}
```

- See example #1 from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

---

Use `or die(mysqli_error($dbLink))` to `mysqli_query()` which would have signaled the error.

- **http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php**

---

**Edit:**

Try the following. You may need to modify `$row[0]` and `rand(0,$count)` as `1` depending on the column number.

```
$result = $dbLink->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable")
while ($row=$result->fetch_row()) { $count = $row[0]; }
$random = rand(0,$count);
echo $random;
```

Comment: error reporting returns the following error "rand() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given..."

Comment: @Sangeet Why not just use MySQL's `RAND()` function? I.e. `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: I would like speed to be of priority.

Comment: @Sangeet Reload my answer and look near the bottom under **Edit**

Comment: The script echo's "0". Modifying `$row[0]` and `rand(0, $count)` to 1 echo's "Notice: Undefined offset: 1.." and "0".

Comment: @Sangeet Then try Meda's solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/26194874/ - has also answered.

Comment: Never mind sorry. Found out that it was returning no result because there wasn't any entries in the database. Thanks for your help. Your script helped my realize.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

$amount = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM table";

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to execute the MySQL-query:

```
$amount = $dbLink->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM table")->fetch_assoc();
$rannmr = rand(1, $amount[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never executed the query, you need more logic

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($dbLink, "SELECT MAX(id) as amount FROM `table`")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $amount = $row['amount']; 
        $rannmr = rand(1, $amount);            
    }else{
        echo 'no row found';
    }
}
mysqli_close($dbLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't seem to see the line of code which actually does the query:

Try this: Using the object-oriented mysqli approach

```
<?php

// Connect to the database
    $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error()); }


$amount = "SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM 'table'";

// Do the actual query : 
$run_query = $dbLink->mysql->query($amount);
// Retrieve the values:
$result = $run_query->fetch_array(); 
// Do the rand function together with the retrieved value
$rannmr = rand(1, $result['max_id']);

// Now you can echo the variable:
echo $rannmr;



// Close the mysql connection
mysqli_close($dbLink);

?>
```

Thanks!!